Pull strength of an electromagnet during linear motion
Consider an electromagnet which is attached to a battery rated with some input voltage (\$V_0\$). Now, we are given a plot of its pull force vs. distance for a given ferromagnetic piece of mass \$m_0\$ (say a block of iron). If I am correct, the pull force varies quadratically with distance.
For example, for a permanent magnet the plot varies like below (source: https://www.first4magnets.com/tech-centre-i61/information-and-articles-i70/how-is-the-strength-of-a-magnet-measured-i81): 
Now assuming the iron piece is held at some distance (\$d_0\$) from the electromagnet and then released. Can the final velocity of the iron piece (before impact between the two) be calculated using the force/acceleration graph as it is. Or do we have to consider some sort of back EMF generated inside the iron piece and the electromagnet too (as the iron piece moves towards the electromagnet) that will affect the velocity of the iron piece?
Essentially, I am unclear about the concept of back-EMF during linear motion and how it affects the motion i.e. can the force distance graph be used as it is to calculate velocity similar to classical mechanics or are there other things to consider when using electromagnets?

For systems with significant electromagnetic interactions, incorporating back-EMF and eddy current effects is necessary for accurate modelling.

i understand the comment that we should consider back EMF. But, this gives no clue (for the force-distance plot similar to above) how the back EMF affects the linear motion i.e. how the distance velocity plot would look like qualitatively (taking Back EMF into consideration). Can you please elaborate.

This phenomenon occurs due to Faraday's Law of Induction, which states that a change in the magnetic flux through a loop induces an electromotive force (EMF) in the loop. Thus the voltage applied to the coil is opposed by the BEMF and will reduce the static force curve.
The work done in a static F*d curve would be the area under the curve by integration will be much less in the release and return of the iron piece.
Thus energy is not stored with this motion.
There will also be force vs velocity limiting factors that depend on losses with the inductance/resistance ratio, L/R which defines the time constant to reach 63.3% of the current from a step voltage, translating into some linear velocity limit.
I would imagine return velocity will also increase exponentially inverse to distance so that the force tends to flatten out or with very light objects be somewhat parabolic and depending on the mutual coupling.  The force tends to rise then fall towards zero as it reaches a maximum velocity with BEMF approaching the applied voltage.
That may be analogous to a motor spinning up to max speed at no load and no force left to go any faster.
But I'll let you decide how the return force looks and what all of the factors are.
